# CSV date format issue while showing the records

Tags: date, csv, date-format

In my application, user select in which format they want the report. They enter one number which is format like 2000-1-4 and then they select CSV format and the data according to this number gets populated in that CSV.
Now the problem is when they enter this number which can be a date like 2012-1-4 then in CSV this number gets converted into 1/4/2012 which is wrong but when they give number like   883-17-8 then its coming as it is which is fine.
Is there any way i can resolve this? Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

How the value is displayed depends on regional settings of operating system. (E.g. for windows 7 see Region and Language). In additional seetings there is also spcified CSV separator (List separator), etc..

Comment: But dont you think that will affect my other columns as well which are suposed to come in Date Format?

Comment: Those settings are global (for system). They are used e.g. by MS Excel. There is no way how to force Excel to display CSV values the way you want.

Comment: You are not supposed to change those system settings. They just give you good reference why your values are displayed in the way they are displayed.

Comment: IMHO, csv format is 'comma separated value' format.. it doesn't store "formatiing" like xls xlsx format. Thus, to be safe, disable/remove all formatting/special format from your application.. (I'm referring to "In my application." in you question).